# how can I translate this c language syntax into c++

Tags: c++

How can I translate this c language syntax into c++?

```
int age=19;
printf("my age is %d years old", age);
```

Comment: This is C++ using the CRT!

Comment: I switched the tag from C++/CLI to just C++. I'm assuming that this is not intended to target Microsoft's .Net runtime.

Comment: C++ supports a large set of C, so printf is supported as well (include <stdio.h>)

Answer (score 0):

This is C++ using the CRT.

But you can use cout...

```
int age = 19;
cout << "my age is " << age << " years old":
```

Answer (score 0):

// first include header file

```
#include <iostream>
```

// then write your code

```
   cout << "my age is : " << str;
   cout << "years old" << endl;
```